# php foreach loop only returns first character of each string

Tags: php, string, foreach

I have the below code. It is only returning the first charater of a string.

```
    $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('connection_write');
$str = 'something to search for';
$fields = 'content_field1, content_field2, content_field3, content_field4';
$idFields = 'id_field1, id_field2, id_field3, id_field4';
$tables = 'table1, table2, table3, table4';
$table = explode(', ', $tables);
$field = explode(', ', $fields);
$rowId = explode(', ', $idFields);

$i=1;
while ($i<4) {
    $f = $field[$i];
    $id = $rowId[$i];
    $sql = $conn->select()->from($table[$i], array($f, $id))->where($f . " LIKE ?", '%' . $str . '%');
    $result = $conn->fetchRow($sql);

    foreach ($result as $row) {
    var_dump($row[$id]);
    }

    $i++;
}
```

However, if I use `var_dump($row);` the entire string from both the id fields and the content fields are outputted.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A string is viewed as an array of characters, so `$test = "abcs"` also would act like `$test = array('a','b','c','d')` so it would be accessed as `$test[2]` would show `c` as its the 3rd index in the array of chars!

Comment: @RobertPitt: I would notice that analogue "string == array" is true only for accessing elements. In other cases strings and arrays behave differently.

Comment: Yes they do behave differently, The way I think of it is that Strings hae ArrayAccess implemented into them!

Comment: @RobertPitt: they don't implement ArrayAccess interface - unset operation is not defined for strings. The implementation is complete internal, it has nothing to do with outer interfaces.

Comment: I never said it did :/, I stated "The way I think of it", as i don't know fully the process of it.

Comment: @RobertPitt: oh, it is my language issues, sorry then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if I use var_dump($row); the entire string from both the id fields and the content fields are outputted.

well, why do you use `var_dump($row[$id]);` which exactly equals to "take $id'th char from $row string" then?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to isolate the id fields in the result.

Comment: @Jack: `var_dump($result);` do you see key `id` there? If so - use `$result['id']` instead of loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
```

$result is a list of rows you selected from the table. Each $row is a string.
$row[$id] simply selects the $id'th character from this row string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem has to do with the fact that $result is an array (possibly an associative array) of strings. (I'm not familiar with Mage, but I'm assuming that fetchRow() returns only a single row and not all of your rows.)

Therefore, what's happening is you've probably got something like this:

```
$result = array("tom","dick","harry");
```

When you run `foreach($result as $row)`, $row looks like "tom", "dick", and "harry" on each iteration.

Because $row is a string, calling `$row[$id]` makes PHP attempt to get get a single character from the $row string. Because it's expecting $id to be an integer in this case, it's probably interpreting "id_field1" as 0, which will end up returning the first character of your string.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to get back, but most likely this can be solved by changing your foreach section to be something like...

```
foreach ($result as $resultColumn) {
   var_dump($resultColumn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

->fetch() is not needed when fetching data by using foreach statement like in your code (Please see examples below). If you use ->fetch() unnecessarily, this situation often occurs (I experienced this too..)

foreach statement and while statement have the following relationship. Please consider rewriting the code, referring to this:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM Entry');

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  echo $row['title'], $row['content'];
}
//this while statement above is equivalent to the foreach statement below

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
//->fetch() is not needed for foreach statement!
  echo $row['title'], $row['content'];
}
```